# Upper bound for m.g.f

Tags: discrete-data, moment-generating-function, bounds

$X$ is a discrete random variable from power series family (e.g., binomial, poisson etc.). is it possible to find an upper bound for the m.g.f of $X$?

N.B: from stack exchange I obtained the following statement:
Suppose $X$ is a bounded zero-mean random variable taking on values in $[−σ,σ]$ and let $G(t)=E[e^{tX}]$ be its MGF. From a bound used in a proof of Hoeffding's Inequality, we have that $G(t)=E[e^{tX}] \le \exp(σ^2t^2/2)$

But this is for bounded r.v. Can we found some similar m.g.f bound for discrete r.v from psd family?

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible.

The most general discrete variable $X$ is supported on a countable set of real numbers $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n, \ldots$ with associated positive probabilities $p_i = e^{q_i}.$  By definition,

$$\phi_X(t) = E\left[e^{tX}\right] = \sum_{i} p_i e^{t x_i} = \sum_{i} \exp(q_i + t x_i),$$

which is a sum of strictly positive values.

To say that this variable is unbounded means for every natural number $N$ there exists an index $i(N)$ for which $|x_{i(N)}| \gt N.$  Pick any real number $t$ for which

$$t \operatorname{sgn}(x_{i(N)}) \gt \frac{\log(N) - q_{i(N)}}{N}$$

and by neglecting all the terms in the sum but the one with index $i(N),$ estimate

$$\phi_X(t) \ge  \exp\left({q_{i(N)} + tx_{i(N)}}\right) \gt e^{\log(N)}= N.$$

This proves $\phi_X$ is unbounded.  (Indeed, it shows $\phi_X$ is unbounded on at least one of the intervals $[0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty, 0]$.)

Comment: the question is not so well worded so I can't be sure, but I think that the OP asked for an upper bound for the MGF depending on $t$, for a discrete (and unbounded ?) random variable. Good, clear answer though (+1).

Comment: @StratosFair That's a good point.  I apologize for responding to an ambiguous question without first requesting or attempting a clarification.  I was reacting to the reference to *bounded* variables where $|X|\le M\le \infty,$, for which the upper bound $\exp(\sigma^2 t^2/2)$ provides an upper bound $\exp(\sigma^2 M^2/2)$ for all $t.$